# How do I apply the texture paint to a specific object?

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting

I am new to Blender and I am using Blender 2.8. I want the texture paint that I created to apply only to the character's jacket but it's applying to the entire body. How do I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Possible answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21306/how-to-fill-element-with-color-in-texture-painting/72617#72617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into edit mode. Select the polygons that you want a different material on. Go to the Material tab. Click (+) to add a new Material slot. Choose a material  or create a new one and then click "Assign".